# Not able to change the background color and couldn't find the element

Tags: css, sass

I'm trying to change the background color from white to     `background: #f8f8f8;` but isn't able to find the div or area which needs the css. Screenshot attached,
Link https://dev5.urban.com.au/projects/australia-108-70-southbank-boulevard-southbank

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to change `background color`. It's because `owl-dots` are having a space. Set owl dots or hide the dots.
Have a look in this screenshot.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Set `margin-top: 0 !important;` on the div `owl-dots`.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Change the background color of `body`.

give this to your style

```
body.listing-alternate-display {
   background: #f8f8f8 !important;
}
```

[image]